# Fetch local JSON and display a list in Next.js. Property 'data' does not exist on type String

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-hooks, next.js

I am trying to get the names displayed of a 'Crate' (a crate full of records/albums), derived from a local JSON file. But it's not showing up. Should I be using params? Should I have not stringified the JSON? VSC tells me Property 'data' does not exist on type String. Before this I received an error that crates.map is not a function, indicating that the JSON was an object not an array.

public/data.json

```
    "crates": [{
            "id": 1,
            "nameCrate": "Pauls crate",
            "albums": ["Blue Bossa", "Boogarins"]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "nameCrate": "Lauras crate",
            "albums": ["ABBA", "Blof"]
        }
    ]
}
```

index.tsx

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function Home() {

  interface Crate {
    id: string;
    nameCrate: string;
    albums: string;
  }

  const [crates, setCrates] = useState<Array<Crate>>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('data.json',{
      headers : { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
       }
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((resJson) => {const data = JSON.stringify(resJson)
    setCrates(data.data)})
  }, [])

  console.log(crates)



  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

<main>
  Main
  {crates && crates.map((crate) => (<div key={crate.id} {...crates}>{crate.nameCrate}</div>))}

</main>

      <footer className="bg-black">
       <div>This is the footer </div>
      </footer>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to stringify since response is json

```
{ 
    const data = resJson.crates
    setCrates(data)// set crates 
})
```